# Adjust size of File Upload Button

Tags: file-upload, button

I want to adjust the size of the "Browse" section seen in the file upload button in HTML. When I try to adjust the size using "size" or "width" attributes, only the whole size is reduced. But I want only the size of the "Browse" button part to be reduced and not the textbox part which displays file path. Can I do this without using CSS? If yes , how?

Answer (score 0):

The file input element is notoriously difficult to style.  One of the problems is that it's really a single element, even though it renders as two elements.

One approach is to obscure the entire element behind the scenes and present the user with custom elements instead.  Here's [an article](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_custom_file_input_book_designing_with_progressive_enhancement/) about it.  Basically the file input element is hidden and some custom elements backed by some JavaScript are handling the UI and passing the necessary information to the file input.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to change the appearance of the Browse button as it is typically hardwired into the browser.

However, at [Quirksmode.org|Styling an input type="file"](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html), there is a long post that discusses complex CSS techniques for changing the appearance of file input elements.